# Oracle APEX, autonumber not working?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle, and new to Oracle Application Express.

I'm working through a manual and I'm trying to create a table with 3 fields:

USER_ID: Number, Primary Key, Autonumber

USER_NAME: VARCHAR2, Unique

PASSWORD: VARCHAR2

I used the APEX SQL Workshop wizard to create the table, but when I try to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO Schema.USERS (USER_NAME,PASSWORD) VALUES ('planet','password');
```

...I get told that a unique constraint on the Primary Key is violated.

A trigger was automatically created by the Table Creation wizard. It looks like this:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_USERS" 
  before insert on "USERS"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."USER_ID" is null then
    select "USERS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."USER_ID" from sys.dual;
  end if;
end;
```

I was under the impression this would automatically find the highest numeric value in the USER_ID field of USERS and automatically assign an incremented value to each new INSERT, but this doesn't appear to be happening.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks

pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sequences**: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

> *(Quoted from linked article)*
>   In Oracle, you can create an autonumber field by using sequences. A
>   sequence is an object in Oracle that is used to generate a number
>   sequence. This can be useful when you need to create a unique number
>   to act as a primary key.
>
> ...
>
> This insert statement would insert a new record into the suppliers
>   table. The supplier_id field would be assigned the next number from
>   the supplier_seq sequence. The supplier_name field would be set to
>   Kraft Foods.

You said:

> I was under the impression this would automatically find the highest
>   numeric value in the `USER_ID` field of `USERS` and automatically
>   assign an incremented value to each new INSERT, but this doesn't
>   appear to be happening.

No. A sequence will simply generate the next value based on the last value and the increment, and is not tied to your data.

```
select nvl(max(user_id), 0) + 1 
  into v_next_val 
  from users
```

Is something that would look at your data and increment the highest `USER_ID` with `1`.

If right now you are getting constraint violations due to the primary key on `USER_ID`, this might mean you have inserted data into your users table, and this data contained values for the `USER_ID` column. 
For instance, say created 3 records and manually assigned a value to `USER_ID` without using a sequence

```
insert into users (user_id, user_name) values (1, 'John');
insert into users (user_id, user_name) values (2, 'Jerry');
insert into users (user_id, user_name) values (3, 'Bob');
```

When you then start using the sequence (or create it only then), the sequence will start at the specified start with value = `1`. 
So doing

```
insert into users (user_name) values ('planet');
```

would generate a constraint violation because sequence.nextval would be 1.

Comment: Thanks Tom, very much appreciate your answer! pt

Answer (score 2):

As @Tom said, if you've inserted rows in the table which specified a value for USER_ID the use of the sequence was bypassed and you may now have rows in the table with USER_ID values which duplicate values which would be fetched from the sequence; thus, upon inserting new rows you're getting a PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT VIOLATION error.  To work around this write a little script which "consumes" values from the sequence and just discards them, as in the following:

```
DECLARE
  n       NUMBER := 122;  -- or however many sequence values you need to consume
  seqVal  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
    SELECT USERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO seqVal FROM DUAL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The other alternative is to drop the sequence and recreate it with the minimum value greater than the maximum value of USERS.USER_ID.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Or, as the techonthenet article describes: set increment to 121, do one nextval, and reset increment to 1. Also, if you recreate the sequence i'd not necessarily touch the minimum value, but rather the start with value.

Comment: Thanks Bob, wish I could mark more than one post as the answer -- I haven't even met the threshold yet for upvoting posts. However, I still appreciate your input! pt

Answer (score -1):

This can be helpful:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "TR_USER"
before insert on "USER"
for each row
begin   
   if :NEW."IDUSER" is null then
     select max("IDUSER")+1 into :NEW."IDUSER" from USER;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Never ever user max(id)+1 for populating sequences. This will fail in a multi-user environment.